# svn files delete

Tags: svn

I have deleted some files in my project but when dooing commit directories are not synchronized. I would like to files in repository to be deleted as well.

How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you just delete them with `rm` or did you use `svn delete` ?

If you use the second option, then your commit will effectively delete the files from the repository.

**Edit**: Translation for windows/tortoise:

If you deleted the files "normally" then you need to update your folder to make them reappear and then you have to delete them with tortoise (right click, ..., delete).

Comment: I'm using tortoise svn and just commit

Comment: Perform an update to recreate the folders you delete and use the tortoise delete afterwards. Then commit your changes.

Comment: thanks so everytime I add or delete file need to do it using tortoise svn?

Comment: Yes. Otherwise SVN will not know what that the new files are versioned or if you really want to delete the files. But this is normal: for example you can add unversioned files in a versioned folder, for example, objects files resulting from a compilation, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Open the repository browser and delete the files you want to just like you would in Windows Explorer